# Unable to view uploaded photos/videos on iCloud.com

Tags: icloud

I can see that my photos/videos are backed up to iCloud, however, when I log into icloud.com to view them from my PC, the images do not populate.

The app has been installed onto my computer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have made a backup of your device and the photos it doesn't work. For synchronisation of your photos you need to use iCloud Photo Library which was introduced with iOS 8.